# Which is the best approach to read a slowing change lookup and enrich a streaming input collection?

Tags: java, parallel-processing, apache-flink, apache-beam, flink-streaming

I'm using Apache beam, with a streaming collection of 1.5GB.
My lookup table is a JDBCio mysql response.

When I run the pipeline without the side input, my job will finish in about 2 minutes. When I run my job with the side input, my job will never finish, stucks and dies.

Here is the code I use to store my lookup (~1M records)

```
  PCollectionView<Map<String,String>> sideData = pipeline.apply(JdbcIO.<KV<String, String>>read()
.withDataSourceConfiguration(JdbcIO.DataSourceConfiguration.create(
       "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver", "jdbc:mysql://ip")
      .withUsername("username")
      .withPassword("password"))
      .withQuery("select a_number from cell")
      .withCoder(KvCoder.of(StringUtf8Coder.of(), StringUtf8Coder.of()))
      .withRowMapper(new JdbcIO.RowMapper<KV<String, String>>() {
      public KV<String, String> mapRow(ResultSet resultSet) throws Exception {
        return KV.of(resultSet.getString(1), resultSet.getString(1));
      }
})).apply(View.asMap());
```

Here is the code of my streaming collection

```
pipeline
.apply("ReadMyFile", TextIO.read().from("/home/data/**")
.watchForNewFiles(Duration.standardSeconds(60),  Watch.Growth.<String>never()))
.apply(Window.<String>into(new GlobalWindows())
.triggering(Repeatedly.forever(AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane().plusDelayOf(Duration.standardSeconds(30))))
.accumulatingFiredPanes()
.withAllowedLateness(ONE_DAY))
```

Here is the code of my parDo to iterate on each event row (of 10M records)

```
  .apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<KV<String,Integer>,KV<String,Integer>>() {
  @ProcessElement
  public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
    KV<String,Integer> i = c.element();
    String sideInputData = c.sideInput(sideData).get(i.getKey());
    if (sideInputData == null) {
      c.output(i);
    } 
  }
 }).withSideInputs(sideData));
```

I'm using a flink cluster, but using direct runner outputs the same.

**cluster:**

2 cpu
6 cores
24gb ram

What am I doing wrong?
[I've followed this](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/guide-to-common-cloud-dataflow-use-case-patterns-part-1)

Comment: Did you also try to run on a sample of the input? Make the sample as small as 1k records and check what is happening. Can you also observe GC (JVisualVM or JConsole...) and print that here?

Comment: @ArvidHeise, i've reduced to 1k, it is much faster! And the job finish quick, don't get stuck or dies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to create a "cache" MAP.

The sideInput only triggers once and then I cache it into a map equivalent suctruture.

So, that I'm avoiding doing a sideInput for every processElement.

```
.apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<KV<String,Integer>,KV<String,Integer>>() {
  @ProcessElement
  public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
   if (isFirstTime) {
        myList = c.sideInput(sideData);
    }
    isFirstTime = false;
    boolean result = myList.containsKey(c.element().getKey());         
    if (result == false) {
      c.output(i);
    } 
  }
 }).withSideInputs(sideData));
```

Answer (score 0):

If it runs with much less data, I suspect that the program is using up all memory of the java process. You can monitor that through JVisualVM or JConsole. There are many articles that cover the problem, I just stumbled upon [this one](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-find-and-fix-memory-leaks-in-your-java-appl) with a quick google search.

If memory runs out, your java process is mostly busy with cleaning up memory and you see a huge performance decline. At some point, java gives up and fails.

To solve the issue, it should be enough to increase the java heap size. How you increase that depends on how and where you execute it. Look at for Java's `-Xmx` parameter or some heap option in beam.

Comment: I can't increase heap size, i'm at maximum ram. The thing is, I can't see any leak here (in code)

Comment: This has nothing to do with leaks. You are applying a global window, which by definition has to collect data (=keep data in memory) until it is evicted. Thus, simply by having much more events per given time interval, you need to also provide more memory. Btw allowed lateness _adds_ to the eviction time, so you keep all data points for at least one day.

Comment: That makes sense, I'll try to use a different windowing approach. I was using global because I want to stream and SUM user score after new event